# Can not insert data mysql using python with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python which version is 3.x.x . In python 3.x.x as you know there is no library for MySQL. For this reason i'm trying to use pymysql for connect my database. While using pymysql , I can not insert data my database.(I'm BEGINNER).
When i run this script i got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "home/pi ......
cur.execute(sql)
Name:Error: cur is not defined.
```

How can i fix this ? How can i define cursor.execute? I called library for this why i have to define this again ?

Here is my code. I deleted the part which is not neccessarry for this problem.

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import glob
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from time import strftime

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-000008a43c0e')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Connect MySQL
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='mehmetali',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='temp-at-interrupt')


cursor= cnx.cursor()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Get Temperature Values.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Insert new data
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if True:
    temp=read_temp()
    print(temp)
    datetimeWrite = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    print (datetimeWrite)
    #sql= ("""INSERT INTO `temp-at-interrupt` (Date,Time,Temperature) VALUES (%s,%s,%s )""",(datetimeWrite,temp))
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO `temp-at-interrupt` (`Date`,`Time`,`Temperature`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s' )""",(datetimeWrite,temp))
try:
    print ("Writing to database...")
# Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
# Commit your changes in the database
    cnx.commit()
    print ("Write Complete")
except:
# Rollback in case there is any error
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    print ("Failed writing to database")
```

**UPDATE** : When i follow the sequence     *'' You have to set up your connection, define your cursor, run your queries, and after you've finished querying you can close the connection.''* I fixed my errors. But im still stuck here. 
My output like this.

```
25.35 C
2018-04-20 22:21:04
Writing to Database...
Failed writing to database
```

Where i'm wrong here?

Comment: While you may be programming on Ubuntu, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) may be better for programming questions, which this primarily is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood how to use the python interface.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='******',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='temp-at-interrupt')
cnx.close()
```

Here you connect, and then close the connection. After this, without ever defining your cursor `cur` you attempt to execute a query with it. This won't work.

You have to set up your connection, define your cursor, run your queries, and after you've finished querying you can close the connection.

[The mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) provides this example, which shows the flow of it:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

tomorrow = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)

add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
add_salary = ("INSERT INTO salaries "
              "(emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) "
              "VALUES (%(emp_no)s, %(salary)s, %(from_date)s, %(to_date)s)")

data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

# Insert new employee
cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)

emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

# Insert salary information
data_salary = {
  'emp_no': emp_no,
  'salary': 50000,
  'from_date': tomorrow,
  'to_date': date(9999, 1, 1),
}
cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)

# Make sure data is committed to the database
cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Here you clearly see the flow of connecting to the database, creating a cursor, executing queries, committing the result to the DB, and finally cleaning up and closing the connection.

Comment: i updated my post can you check ?

Comment: Print your SQL statement, and check that it's valid. Look into [showing errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html). A quick glance indicates that your number of columns and number of parameters does not match.

Comment: hmmm i think i got it . I create table from my phpadmin (localhost) not created from with code. Is this make a difference ?

Comment: No, that does not make a difference, as long as data types are correct. But print the sql statement, and try it in mysql directly. This will hilight any mistakes.

Comment: I can insert data in phpmyadmin manually. Probably , i can not execute the ''INSERT into 'TAB_TEMP'  code in my script. This code is not reach my phpadmin or my script write and rollback sametime.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement tries to insert 3 values (Date, Time, Temperature) but you supply only 2 (datetimeWrite,temp).  It cannot work. 
Besides, as indicated by vidarlo, you really should look into errors.  Simply putting the print statement indicated in reference can help you a lot:

```
...
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
...
```